# Why Nullable type must have struct constraint

Tags: c#, oop, struct

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SomeFunction<int>()==null);
        var temp = new SomeClass<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(temp.SomeFunction() == null);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static public T? SomeFunction<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return null;
    }

    public class SomeClass<T> where T : struct 
    {
        public T? SomeFunction()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, why does a nullable type need the struct constraint?
I don't understand why struct is the right syntax and not object or class.

Answer (score 8):

Because `Nullable<T>` (or `T?`) also restricts `T` to be a struct.

So, for `SomeFunction<T>`'s generic type parameter `T` to fulfill `Nullable<T>`'s requirements, `SomeFunction<T>` must *also* declare the same constraints.

Here's another example of how constraints must be *propagated*:

```
interface ISomeInterface { }
class MyClass<T> where T: ISomeInterface { }

class Program
{
    //MyClass's constaints must be "re-declared" here
    public MyClass<T> SomeFunction<T>() where T : ISomeInterface
    {
    }
}
```

And why does `Nullable<T>` do that? Because a nullable reference type would make no sense. Refence types *are* already nullable.

Comment: +1 Also - The fact that reference types already nullable doesn't proof the fact of the question : "_why struct is the right syntax_"

Comment: @RoyiNamir The first sentence explains that.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know : why they choose struct in first place to refelect nullables...

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm not sure I understand... are you asking "why is `Nullable<T>` to structs, and not to classes"?

Comment: I'm not asking. I'm just saying that the OP wants to know (IIUC)  - why nullables are stored in struct  - at first place

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't think he meant to ask why nullables are structs themselves. I think he was asking why must `T` be a struct.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you are correct. OP exactly wants to know that only but I would say that the reason is because spec says so.

Comment: @Rahul "I don't understand why struct is the right syntax" I read this as - "Why does `SomeFunction` have to declare `where T : struct`?". The fact that `Nullable<T>` is a struct itself is irrelevant, you'd still have to add the `where T:struct` constraint even if `Nullable<T>` was a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

`T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>` and `Nullable<T>` requires that `T` be a struct:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

Answer (score 0):

`Nullable<T>` is a struct (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)) however it is the only struct that does not satisfy the struct constraint. On a side note you cannot use a Nullable as a generic type parameter when either the class or struct constraints is used.

The basic idea of `Nullable<T>` is to have a storage location that can contain T or can represent "the value is missing"